# Why were Chinese readings imported along with kanji?

Tags: kanji, history, onyomi, old-japanese

I have been studying Japanese for a little more than a year now,and I've been learning kanji for a few months.

I understand the basics about readings, but I don't really get the historic reason of why the Chinese readings were imported along with kanji.

If I understand correctly, back then Old Japanese was already a language by itself, only lacking a writing system which was imported from China.

Now, I understand that maybe they took some kanji which represented things for which they didn't have a Japanese word, and thus used the Chinese sounds they heard.

But seeing the huge amount of compound words which use onyomi, it's impossible to think that none of them were used before with their native pronunciation, especially since there are also a lot of words which having more that one kanji use kunyomi.
For example, some vocabulary words I've learnt recently are: 大雨 ( おおあめ, kunyomi) and 小川 ( おがわ, kunyomi).But 火山 is かざん (onyomi).Maybe the concept "volcano" didn't have a word for itself in Japanese, but why create it imitating Chinese instead of joining their native words (ひ and やま)?

Comment: Why does English have so many borrowings from French, Greek, and Latin, even where it has its own native words (in such cases as *anger* vs *rage*)?

Comment: But I feel this is a different case, not just borrowing new words or new ways to say them,_"Japan" itself_ is read with onyomi (although I think I read that they were "forced" to do so by the Chinese)

Comment: How could the Chinese possibly force them to do that? The very choice of name 日本 is usually interpreted as a not-so-subtle jibe at the Chinese court - "greetings from the land of the rising sun to the land of the setting sun".

Comment: @Matt The theory that associates 日本 with that document is not widely supported (or almost considered a myth). And I believe being located in west didn't have derogative nuance back then, if any, it's description of 天子.

Comment: @Matt "Another 8th-century chronicle, True Meaning of Shiji (史記正義), however, states that the Chinese Empress Wu Zetian ordered a Japanese envoy to change the country's name to Nippon. " from Wikipedia,I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Comment: @user4092, Interesting, thanks for the correction. Incidentally, the intended takeaway of the story is not "Japan insulted China by calling them western/old/finished" so much as "Japan dared to imply that its ruler was an equal of China's, just in a different place". user2859982 - Yeah, this document exists and it does say that ("武后改倭國為日本國"). But there are other Chinese sources which say that the name change came from the Japanese side, and I am more inclined to believe that since obviously they had the motivation, and how would Wu Zetian have enforced such a ruling?

Comment: (I should say "intended takeaway as I understand it"; clearly my understanding is not complete though since I still believed what is apparently now considered a myth...)

Answer (score 1):

People didn't import kanji to assign them to Japanese words but to study Buddhism or to communicate with Chinese diplomats, in short, to read Chinese. It's no wonder that Chinese reading was imported when they needed to read Chinese.

(As for volcano, Mt Aso or Mt Asama are a word that stands for volcano but they are simultaneously a proper noun. As for Japan, "Yamato" domestically more often meant a country in current Nara prefecture or "Yamatai" that is so called since Moto'ori Norinaga than the nation in the archipelago.)